# ember.js tutorial: is really working Mirage addon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

Following the ember.js tutorial, I get stuck in this step:

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/tutorial/installing-addons/
(the exact part when Mirage add-on is used.

Is there anything else to do to get shown the Mirage data included in the `mirage/config.js` file?

No matter what I change in that file... that I'll keep having the data served from the previous `app/routes/rentals.js`.

Did anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything else to do to get shown the Mirage data included in the mirage/config.js file?

Yes, you need to change your route so it will make ajax request to receive data. Usually it's done with Ember Data. Tutorial explains this later, in "[Using Ember Data](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/tutorial/ember-data/)" step. It will not work until then.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. It was a matter of applying patience. Three more chapters and I got it ;). The tutorial should warn about it though.

Comment: Would one of you open an issue or a pr to the guides? That should definitely be fixed ...

Comment: That's totally fine. But having an issue mentioning that Mirage is introduced before it is used which causes problems in the tutorial would be very useful

Comment: I'll take a deeper look to the tutorial and if I don't see any comment I I'll open an issue